# SWIG: How to add a specified C# code block to all generated C# methods

Tags: c#, c++, c, swig

I'm using SWIG to generate C# bindings to my C APIs.
I'd like to add a fixed code block to all my generated C# methods ideally without going through specific typemaps.

Is this possible?

UPDATE:

An example would be like this:

```
class MyClass {

.....

public void MyMethod()
{
    // A block of code that will appear in all my methods.

   // my working code 1.

}



public void MyMethod_2()
{
    // A block of code that will appear in all my methods.

   // my working code 2.

}

.....

}
```

That's to say I'd like to generate code unrelated to typemap, or exceptions, it's just a few lines of code (e.g., the above "A block of code that will appear in all my methods." ) that would be inserted into all generated methods.

I know that SWIG has special commands such as **csbody** to insert interface-level code, but I cannot find anything about what I wanted.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "fixed code block", can you give a concrete example with code?

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest you can get to this is to abuse `%exception`. That inserts per function code, except it's on the C++ side not the C# side. You can however make that equivalent because you can always do whatever you wanted to do in C# from the C++ native calls. You could even just arrange for the C++ to call some static function that does whatever you want your fixed block to do.

Example:

```
%module test

%exception {
  // Some magical code goes here
  $action
}

class MyClass {
public:
  void MyMethod();
  void MyMethod2();
};
```

Generates a rapper with extra C++ code before every function call.

Comment: Thanks Flexo. I know %exception but I do want something visible to human on C# end. But you are right that one can achieve much the same functionality from C++ side. It's just not what I want for this question.

Answer (score 0):

1) make class partial

```
%typemap(csclassmodifiers) MyClass "public partial class"
```

2) add missing code in %pragma(csharp) moduleimports

```
%pragma(csharp) moduleimports= %{

public partial class MyClass
{
    public void MyMethodN()
    {
    ...
    }
}

%}
```